REST API to integrate SOAR with BMC Remedy
We've been trying for weeks to integrate IBM SOAR with BMC Remedy to no avail. We keep getting an error 500.
This is the playbook in IBM SOAR:

The problem is on the second "Call REST API" node, the one that's supposed to create a Service Request on BMC Remedy. This is the code inside that node:
import json
# Extract token
token = str(playbook.functions.results.bmc_integration['content']['text'])

# REST API details
inputs.rest_api_verify = False
inputs.rest_api_method = "POST"
inputs.rest_api_url = "http://<url-hidden-for-this-post>:8008/api/arsys/v1/entry/SRM:RequestInterface_Create"

# Correct the headers dictionary
inputs.rest_api_headers = json.dumps({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "AR-JWT {}".format(token)
})

# REST API body using the json module for proper formatting
inputs.rest_api_body = json.dumps({
    "values": {
        "z1D Action": "CREATE",
        "Source Keyword": "IM",
        "TitleInstanceID": "SRGAA5V0FEF9IARVAJLFRUA3EETALB",
        "First Name": "<hidden-for-this-post>",
        "Last Name": "<hidden-for-this-post>",
        "Customer First Name": "<hidden-for-this-post>",
        "Customer Last Name": "<hidden-for-this-post>",
        "OfferingTitle": "REST API TEST SRM Request 1",
        "Short Description": "REST API TEST SRM Request 1",
        "Status": "Submitted",
        "Company": "<hidden-for-this-post>",
        "Customer Company": "<hidden-for-this-post>",
        "Location Company": "<hidden-for-this-post>"
    }})

This is the resulting error code when I try to run the playbook:

For reference, this is the document I used for the integration: How to create a Service Request through REST API
Kindly advise,
Thanks.
